# Screen Recording

Tags: windows, screen-sharing

Our IT department is sometimes tasked with training users in using certain software. Is there a good and inexpensive (Free??) utility for recording Windows screens to do training videos for users? Using Windows as the base OS, outputs screen captures as a .mov or .mp4, maybe? Would like to add voiceover/audio as well if possible.

What is typically used by other sysadmins and IT departments short of aiming a camcorder at a screen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some similar related questions on Superuser.com:

- [What is the best software for desktop recording?](https://superuser.com/questions/6801/what-is-the-best-software-for-desktop-recording)
- [Free desktop recording / screencasting on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/201/free-desktop-recording-screencasting-on-windows)

if you're looking for a free software, consider [uTIPu](http://www.utipu.com/app/) or [Wink](http://www.debugmode.com/wink/). I personally recommend a very powerful, commercial software: [Camtasia Studio](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.asp).

P.S.: if you need the beta-password, it is "ewok.adventure".

Comment: Also in SF: http://serverfault.com/questions/9112/tutorial-training-creation-tools

Comment: I also recommend Wink.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) for a few simple recordings and liked it. It's no cost and open source. I don't know how "supported" it really is anymore, but once I had the AVI files I wanted I was happy... >smile<

Answer (score 1):

CamStudio is ok, Camtasia Studio pretty much sets the bar.

However, the guys that do Camtasia Studio have a free/low cost product that I think rocks.

The product is http://www.jingproject.com/

It is free to use, and if you want to upgrade the cost is really low.

Answer (score 0):

[Mashable](http://mashable.com/2008/02/21/screencasting-video-tutorials/) has a list of a few free and commercial programs that you can look at.